# what "ss+1" means in scanf("%s", ss+1)?

Tags: c

I want to know what do it means to put "+1" in

```
scanf("%s", ss+1)
```

where ss is a string input.

I was solving a question on codechef and when i tried to read some other solutions to get idea about other possible solutions/approaches i fond this in a code.

Comment: What happened when you tried `ss`, `ss+1` and `ss+2`?

Comment: It depends on what `ss` is actually declared as.  If it is a `char[]` or `char*`, then the `+1` is performing pointer arithmetic, the result of which is equivilent to doing `&ss[1]` instead.

Comment: Could you please add declaration of `ss` to your post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have this array:

```
char a[10];
```

We can imagine it looks like this:

```
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
a: |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Suppose you call `scanf` to read a string into the array:

```
scanf("%s", a);
```

Suppose you type "hello".  The array is filled in like this:

```
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
a: | h | e | l | l | o |\0 |   |   |   |   |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Suppose you set up a pointer pointing to an array, and pass that pointer to `scanf`:

```
char b[10];
char *p = b;

scanf("%s", p);
```

Now exactly the same thing happens: `p` points to the beginning of the string, so that's where `scanf` stores the string it reads:

```
       +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    b: | h | e | l | l | o |\0 |   |   |   |   |
       +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
         ^
   +-----|-----+
p: |     *     |
   +-----------+
```

Finally, suppose we have another array and another pointer, but instead of passing the pointer to `scanf`, we add 1 to the pointer before passing it to `scanf`:

```
char c[10];
char *ss = c;

scanf("%s", ss + 1);
```

Now `scanf` receives a pointer to the *second* cell in the array, so that's where it writes the string:

```
        +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
     c: |   | h | e | l | l | o |\0 |   |   |   |
        +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
          ^
    +-----|-----+
ss: |     *     |
    +-----------+
```

This is a little confusing.  It's easier to see if we do the addition off to the side.  It's also easier to see if we pre-fill the array with some other characters:

```
char d[10] = "rstuvwxyz";
```

So initially `d` looks like this:

```
        +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
     d: | r | s | t | u | v | w | x | y | z |\0 |
        +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Now if we do this, and type "hello" again:

```
char *p1 = d;
char *p2 = p1 + 1;

scanf("%s", p2);
```

we end up with a picture that looks like this:

```
    +-----------+
p1: |     *     |
    +-----|-----+
          |
          v
        +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
     d: | r | h | e | l | l | o |\0 | y | z |\0 |
        +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
              ^
        +-----|-----+
    p2: |     *     |
        +-----------+
```

`scanf` reads to where `p2` points, which is one past where `p1` points, which is to the beginning of array `d`.

If you want to confirm what's going on, you can do `printf("%s\n", d)`.
If you do that before the `scanf` call it should print `rstuvwxyz`, and if you do it after the `scanf` call (and if you continue to type "hello") it should print `rhello`.

This may all look rather mysterious at first, but it's a straightforward application of *pointer arithmetic*.  (There's also some slight magic going on when I say things like `p = b`, where `p` is a pointer and `b` is an array, and the pointer ends up pointing to the first character of the array.  That's a hugely important special rule in C, which you'll want to learn about at some point pretty soon.)

There's also another big question unanswered, namely *why* someone would want to write the code this way.  That's harder to explain.  One possibility I can imagine is that it was part of a larger program, that for some reason was trying to store lots of strings into the same array, like this:

```
              +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
longer_array: | c | a | t |\0 | d | o | g |\0 | c | o | w |\0 | b | e | a | r |\0 |
              +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

If in the larger program, the pointer `ss` points to the `\0` a the end of the previous string that was read, then `ss + 1` is indeed the right place to start reading the next one.

(But I'm speculating.  Without seeing the larger program, there's no way of knowing why it wanted to read into `ss + 1`.  Indeed it's an unusual thing to do.)

Answer (score 0):

It simply skips the first character of the string.